# Border radius for the bar chart in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am creating a stacked bar chart using [ng2-chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) which is the Angular-2 version of [ChartJs](http://www.chartjs.org/) .

I am trying to create bar chart with **border- radius** as mentioned in the attached image, but unable to find the option to achieve this,

please suggest me some way to get this.

My code:

```
public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      maxBarThickness: 5,
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],

    },
    barThickness:20,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
          fontColor: '#fff'
      }
  }

  };



<canvas baseChart style="height:350px; width:1150px;" [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend"
[colors]="lineChartColors" [chartType]="barChartType">
 </canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: Might be related to this question --
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254153/how-to-create-rounded-bars-for-bar-chart-js-v2 .  Not sure if it would be the same with ng2-chart

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Using version 3 of chart.js you can easily configure this with the `borderRadius` property. At the time of writing this answer you will need to install the `next` branch of `ng2-charts` since its in its 7'th release candidate for using v3 of chart.js

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      borderRadius: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      borderSkipped: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```