# Rounded corners on chartJS v.2 - bar charts (with negative values)

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, quadratic-curve

I'm styling some chartjs bar charts which need rounded corners at the bar's values (not their base), In most cases this means rounded corners at the top of the bar's however there are also instances where the bars have negative values.

I've used the answer here: [How to create rounded bars for Bar Chart.js v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254153/how-to-create-rounded-bars-for-bar-chart-js-v2) provided by jordanwillis *(https://stackoverflow.com/users/7581592/jordanwillis)* which works great when values are positive but not when values are negative.

See attached example:
[bars with negative values get inverted corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeWIL.png)

I need to update the extension so that the quadraticCurves's in canvas calculate correctly for negatives.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue.
use below code for rounded corners-

```
Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {

      var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
      var vm = this._view;
      var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped, radius;
      var borderWidth = vm.borderWidth;
     // Set Radius Here
      // If radius is large enough to cause drawing errors a max radius is imposed
      var cornerRadius = 20;

      if (!vm.horizontal) {
        // bar
        left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
        right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
        top = vm.y;
        bottom = vm.base;
        signX = 1;
        signY = bottom > top ? 1 : -1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
      } else {
        // horizontal bar
        left = vm.base;
        right = vm.x;
        top = vm.y - vm.height / 2;
        bottom = vm.y + vm.height / 2;
        signX = right > left ? 1 : -1;
        signY = 1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'left';
      }

      // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
      // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
      if (borderWidth) {
        // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
        var barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
        borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize ? barSize : borderWidth;
        var halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
        // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
        var borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left' ? halfStroke * signX : 0);
        var borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right' ? -halfStroke * signX : 0);
        var borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top' ? halfStroke * signY : 0);
        var borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom' ? -halfStroke * signY : 0);
        // not become a vertical line?
        if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
          top = borderTop;
          bottom = borderBottom;
        }
        // not become a horizontal line?
        if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
          left = borderLeft;
          right = borderRight;
        }
      }

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
      ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

      // Corner points, from bottom-left to bottom-right clockwise
      // | 1 2 |
      // | 0 3 |
      var corners = [
        [left, bottom],
        [left, top],
        [right, top],
        [right, bottom]
      ];

      // Find first (starting) corner with fallback to 'bottom'
      var borders = ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right'];
      var startCorner = borders.indexOf(borderSkipped, 0);
      if (startCorner === -1) {
        startCorner = 0;
      }

      function cornerAt(index) {
        return corners[(startCorner + index) % 4];
      }

      // Draw rectangle from 'startCorner'
      var corner = cornerAt(0);
      var width, height, x, y, nextCorner, nextCornerId
      var x_tl, x_tr, y_tl, y_tr;
      var x_bl, x_br, y_bl, y_br;
      ctx.moveTo(corner[0], corner[1]);

      for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        corner = cornerAt(i);
        nextCornerId = i + 1;
        if (nextCornerId == 4) {
          nextCornerId = 0
        }

        nextCorner = cornerAt(nextCornerId);

        width = corners[2][0] - corners[1][0];
        height = corners[0][1] - corners[1][1];
        x = corners[1][0];
        y = corners[1][1];

        radius = cornerRadius;

        // Fix radius being too large        
        if (radius > Math.abs(height) / 2) {
          radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(height) / 2);
        }
        if (radius > Math.abs(width) / 2) {
          radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(width) / 2);
        }

        if (height < 0) {
          // Negative values in a standard bar chart
          x_tl = x; x_tr = x + width;
          y_tl = y + height; y_tr = y + height;

          x_bl = x; x_br = x + width;
          y_bl = y; y_br = y;

          // Draw
          ctx.moveTo(x_bl + radius, y_bl);
          ctx.lineTo(x_br - radius, y_br);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr + radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr);
          ctx.lineTo(x_tl + radius, y_tl);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x_bl, y_bl - radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_bl, y_bl, x_bl + radius, y_bl);

        } else if (width < 0) {
          // Negative values in a horizontal bar chart
          x_tl = x + width; x_tr = x;
          y_tl = y; y_tr = y;

          x_bl = x + width; x_br = x;
          y_bl = y + height; y_br = y + height;

          // Draw
          ctx.moveTo(x_bl + radius, y_bl);
          ctx.lineTo(x_br - radius, y_br);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr + radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr);
          ctx.lineTo(x_tl + radius, y_tl);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x_bl, y_bl - radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_bl, y_bl, x_bl + radius, y_bl);

        } else {
          //Positive Value
          ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
          ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        }
      }

      ctx.fill();
      if (borderWidth) {
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    };
```

I used it for horizontal bar chart. It will draw the chart like below image-[image]

Comment: I need to do it have private effect just to one chart,How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a `cornerRadius` options to the bar chart by customizing `Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw` so whenever you need a border radius to the bars you pass it as an options parameter.

Your options object would match the following if you want a **borderRadius = 8**

```js
const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  cornerRadius: 8,
};
```

Import the following into your code: 
*P.S. if you are not using React, just import it from whatever library you are using and override draw function in the same way!*

```js
// Custom rewrite for radius border on bar draw
// Code from https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts with a few adjustments

import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function ReDraw() {
  const { ctx } = this._chart;
  const vm = this._view;
  let left; let right; let top; let bottom; let signX; let signY; let borderSkipped
  let { borderWidth } = vm;

  // If radius is less than 0 or is large enough to cause drawing errors a max
  // radius is imposed. If cornerRadius is not defined set it to 0.
  let { cornerRadius } = this._chart.config.options;

  if (cornerRadius < 0) { cornerRadius = 0 }
  if (typeof cornerRadius === 'undefined') { cornerRadius = 0 }

  if (!vm.horizontal) {
    left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
    right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
    top = vm.y;
    bottom = vm.base;
    signX = 1;
    signY = bottom > top ? 1 : -1;
    borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
  }

  // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
  // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
  if (borderWidth) {
    // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
    const barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
    borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize ? barSize : borderWidth;
    const halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
    // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
    const borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left' ? halfStroke * signX : 0);
    const borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right' ? -halfStroke * signX : 0);
    const borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top' ? halfStroke * signY : 0);
    const borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom' ? -halfStroke * signY : 0);
    // not become a vertical line?
    if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
      top = borderTop;
      bottom = borderBottom;
    }
    // not become a horizontal line?
    if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
      left = borderLeft;
      right = borderRight;
    }
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
  ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
  ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

  // Corner points, from bottom-left to bottom-right clockwise
  // | 1 2 |
  // | 0 3 |
  const corners = [
    [left, bottom],
    [left, top],
    [right, top],
    [right, bottom],
  ]

  // Find first (starting) corner with fallback to 'bottom'
  const borders = ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right'];
  let startCorner = borders.indexOf(borderSkipped, 0)
  if (startCorner === -1) {
    startCorner = 0;
  }

  function cornerAt(index) {
    return corners[(startCorner + index) % 4];
  }

  // Draw rectangle from 'startCorner'
  let corner = cornerAt(0);
  ctx.moveTo(corner[0], corner[1]);

  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    corner = cornerAt(i);
    let nextCornerId = i + 1;
    if (nextCornerId === 4) {
      nextCornerId = 0;
    }

    const width = corners[2][0] - corners[1][0];
    const height = corners[0][1] - corners[1][1];
    const x = corners[1][0];
    const y = corners[1][1];

    let radius = cornerRadius;

    // Fix radius being too large
    if (radius > Math.abs(height) / 1.5) {
      radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(height) / 1.5);
    }
    if (radius > Math.abs(width) / 1.5) {
      radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(width) / 1.5);
    }

    if (height < 0) {
      // Negative values in a standard bar chart
      const x_tl = x; const x_tr = x + width;
      const y_tl = y + height; const y_tr = y + height;

      const x_bl = x; const x_br = x + width;
      const y_bl = y; const y_br = y;

      // Draw
      ctx.moveTo(x_bl + radius, y_bl);
      ctx.lineTo(x_br - radius, y_br);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius);
      ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr + radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr);
      ctx.lineTo(x_tl + radius, y_tl);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius);
      ctx.lineTo(x_bl, y_bl - radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_bl, y_bl, x_bl + radius, y_bl);
    } else {
      ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
      ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height);
      ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    }
  }

  ctx.fill();
  if (borderWidth) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I am having a stacked chart, it is making all the bars rounded, is there some way by which I can only round the top bar with some value greater than zero?