# How to create rounded bar graph with Angular 7 and Chartjs (v2)

Tags: javascript, angular, graph, chart.js

I am trying to change the bar chart of the chartJs library (version 2.8.0) in angular 7. 
I have seen other answers about overriding the rectangular element's draw method. However, using such an approach presents the following error:

> Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'typeof Chart'

I am importing as follows:

> import {Chart, ChartType, ChartOptions, ChartDataSets} from
>   'chart.js';

I am trying to use the solution presented in the following topic: [How to create rounded bars for Bar Chart.js v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254153/how-to-create-rounded-bars-for-bar-chart-js-v2)

Print of the code:
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cof7H.png)

Comment: please include some screenshots of your error and your code

Comment: I added a print of the code snippet with error

Comment: try to install the types `npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js`

Comment: I tried and even then the error persisted, the error was worked around according to the answer below. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to a typing problem in chartjs with typescript. The `@ts-ignore` annotation was added and everything worked.

Thank god.